# Стек функции в C++

Tags: c++

Если у нас есть функция многих переменных

```cpp
void func(int n, ...);
```

где n - количество последующих аргументов

И далее я вызываю ее

```cpp
func(5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1);
```

С какой точки стека начинается адресация переданных переменных?

В онлайн компиляторе у меня получилось обратиться к ним по формуле

```cpp
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    printf("%d ", *(&n + 2 * i + 5));
```

и получил вывод

```
1 2 3 4 1
```

В компиляторе Visual Studio тот же результат я получаю по формуле

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d ", *(&n + 2 * (i + 1)));
```

От чего это зависит и почему везде умножается на 2, если int имеет размер 4 байта?

Comment: Ни с какой, для обращения к ним есть https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdarg

Comment: @user7860670 А если я все же хочу обращаться по адресам?

Comment: Такой возможности нет. Передавайте аргументы в виде массива.

Comment: Завидна регулярность, с которой возникает этот вопрос... Ну все это нестандарт, зависит от компилятора, режима работы и прочего. Есть стандартный способ — `stdarg` — зачем изобретать какой-то велосипед без колес?

Answer (score 5):

Я так понимаю, что вы ожидали получить правильный результат от такого цикла:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    printf("%d ", *(&n + i + 1));
```

Да действительно, если скомпилировать программу под 32-битный x86-процессор, то данный код скорее всего сработает, т.к. *конвенция вызова процедур* для x86 предполагает расположение *выравненных на 4 байта* параметров в стеке один за другим. Т.к. тип `int` и так занимает 4 байта, то все переданные параметры типа `int` будут идти один за другим (сразу оговорюсь: "скорее всего" - не значит, что "так и будет").

Однако, в приведенных вами примерах вы компилируете программу под 64-битную архитектуру, известную как amd64 или x64 (правильнее, кстати, говорить amd64)! Догадываетесь теперь, откуда появился множитель 2? Обратимся к [*конвенции вызова процедур*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170) для x64. Вот основные интересующие нас положения:

> The x64 Application Binary Interface (ABI) uses a four-register fast-call calling convention by default. Space is allocated on the call stack as a shadow store for callees to save those registers.

> Integer valued arguments in the leftmost four positions are passed in left-to-right order in RCX, RDX, R8, and R9, respectively. The fifth and higher arguments are passed on the stack as previously described. All integer arguments in registers are right-justified, so the callee can ignore the upper bits of the register and access only the portion of the register necessary.

> The callee is responsible for dumping the register parameters into their shadow space if needed.

> If parameters are passed via varargs (for example, ellipsis arguments), then the normal register parameter passing convention applies. That convention includes spilling the fifth and later arguments to the stack. It's the callee's responsibility to dump arguments that have their address taken.

Расшифрую эти цитаты:

1. Первые четыре параметра *размещаются в регистрах*, пространство в стеке для них лишь резервируется.
2. Пятый и все последующие параметры размещаются в стеке.
3. Параметры типа `int` хранятся как *64-битные*, старшие 32 бита которых должны игнорироваться - отсюда и множитель 2 в ваших "формулах".
4. Вызываемая процедура может сохранять первые четыре регистровых параметра в отведённые для них места в стеке (shadow store), если это необходимо. А может и не сохранять, или сохранять в другое место - конвенция это не запрещает.
5. Вызов процедур с переменным числом параметров осуществляется точно так же, как и для обычных процедур - первые четыре параметра в регистрах, остальные - в стеке. При этом отдельно указано, что такая процедура сама ответственна за размещение  параметров в памяти для взятия их адреса. Но при этом ничего не говорится про то, где именно она должна их разместить: в зарезервированные под них места в стеке (shadow store), в области локальных переменных, или где-либо ещё - решение в этом вопросе принимает конкретный компилятор.

Так что рассмотрим второй ваш цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d ", *(&n + 2 * (i + 1)));
```

Тут всё ожидаемо: пареметр `n` и последующие три размещаются функцией `func()` в предназначенных для них местах (shadow store), так что все шесть параметров (длиной в 8 байт) в итоге располагаются один за другим.

Теперь первый цикл:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    printf("%d ", *(&n + 2 * i + 5));
```

А тут уже всё не так ожидаемо. Просто данный компилятор разместил параметр `n` не в shadow store, а в области локальных переменных. По-этому "формула" и приняла вид `*(&n + 2 * i + 5)`, что можно записать как `*((&n + 3) + 2 * (i + 1))`. Здесь число 3 (24 байт) - это расстояние от места размещения параметра `n` до остальных переменных параметров.

Подведём итог: конвенция стандартного вызова процедур для 64-битных программ ничего не говорит о том, каким образом компилятору размещать регистровые параметры в памяти для взятия их адреса. А значит каждый компилятор волен делать это по-своему (вы в этом убедились на двух конкретных примерах). А значит, для доступа к переменным параметрам надо использовать встроенные в язык средства: `va_list`, `va_start`, `va_arg` `va_end`, которые "знают", как правильно обращаться к аргументам для конкретного компилятора и целевой архитектуры процессора. Правильный вариант вашего цикла существует только один, и он выглядит так:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void func(int n, ...)
{
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        printf("%d ", va_arg(args, int));
    va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Умножает я на 2 потому что оптимизирующий компилятор для x64 хранит переменные до 8 байт в 64битах. Это чтоб они читались за меньшее время из памяти.

Полагаться на адрес не стоит потому что компилятор может менять адреса аргументов в зависимости от того какой код выполнялся до и после вызова функции.